# What is the average human lifespan in the 23rd Century?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

I was wondering what the average lifespan of a human (not in a red shirt!) is in the 23rd Century (TOS)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per a quick search on [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Life_span):

> The average Human life span had gradually increased during their
>   history. the average life spans during the 22nd century was about 100
>   years (ENT: "Observer Effect"). This average age was still roughly the
>   same during the 2250, but had risen to 120 by the mid-24th century.
>   However, at some point in history the
>   average lifespan for Humans was only 35, and by 1999 it had become
>   higher than a millennium earlier. (ENT: "Similitude", VOY: "11:59").
>   Leonard McCoy had by 2364 reached the age of 137. (TNG: "Encounter at
>   Farpoint").

So the average human lifespan *had* increased from what we currently have today by the 23rd century.  For more information on other specie's lifespans, click the link I have provided to Memory Alpha.

Answer (score -1):

140-150 seems to be the average by the end of the 24th century. McCoy was 137 in TNG pilot. In TNG era many human characters were well over 100 and still quite healthy and active.

Comment: One data point (McCoy) does not an average make.  Without further cited information or examples, your answer doesn't really add anything to the existing answer from @N_Soong.  Can you give more information to back up your answer and make it more substantive?

Comment: Elias Vaughn (Deep Space Nine novels) lived to be 109. Data's creator, Noonien Soong, also lived to be more than a hundred years old. Both might have lived longer had they not died, so I assume 110 or more is the average human lifespan in TNG era.

Comment: "Both might have lived longer had they not died": that seems reasonable.